# Calculating Rolling Mean with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
sp500['42d'] = np.round(pd.rolling_mean(sp500['Close'], window=42), 2)
```

Hey good morning, I am trying to calculate my rolling mean. However I am returned with

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_mean'
```

I Tried to Write the Code as

```
sp500['42d'] = np.round(pd.DataFrame.rolling(sp500['Close'], window=42), 2).mean()
```

and I was given

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Rolling' and 'float'
```

I do believe that I had gotten my code to run, however it was excluding my '2' which I figure is important otherwise why would it be in the code.

Any one mind help?

Comment: It works like this **sp500['42d'] = np.round(pd.DataFrame.rolling(sp500['Close'], window=42).mean())**

But Don't I need my length of values, which is **2** right? However I input and it says 

WAIT!!! I THINK I GOT IT!!!

**sp500['42d'] = np.round(pd.DataFrame.rolling(sp500['Close'], window=42).mean(),2)**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you got the answer, but this should work:

```
sp500['42d'] = np.round(pd.DataFrame.rolling(sp500['Close'], window=42).mean(),2)
```

Alternatively:

```
sp500['42d'] = np.round(sp500['Close'].rolling(window=42).mean(),2)
```

Comment: Thank You G, I appreciate the way you flipped it too!